# Bullet doesn't move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to create a weapon system. Created a new script for weapon. Everything seems to be working fine other than the bullet. It stays in the same place when I press the fire button, doesn't move at all. The bullet is a prefab.

```
private void Fire()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        firingCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FireContinuously());
        myAnimator.SetBool("Shoot", true);
    }
    else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        StopCoroutine(firingCoroutine);
        myAnimator.SetBool("Shoot", false);
    }

}

private void Pistol()
{
    GameObject laser = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(projectileSpeed * direction, 0);

}
```

Comment: How is the `Fire()` method executed?

Comment: Through Update method. 

void Update()
    {
        Fire();
    }

Comment: Please share more information.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I cannot post comments so I'm going to have to post an answer instead, even though I'm more of asking for clarity.

You haven't really shared enough information as to where Pistol() gets executed and if you have even set up the "Fire1" button in "Edit –> Project Settings –> Input", i.e. if those if-statement bodies even get executed. From what I gather though your bullet gets spawned correctly but simply doesn't move?... if so, then you may simply have a case of your bullet Rigidbody2D being marked kinematic or static.

Comment: Pistol gets called inside IEnumerator.

<!-- language: c# -->

private IEnumerator FireContinuously()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            Pistol();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(projectileFiringPeriod);

        }
    }

<!-- language: c# -->


My bullet is a prefab and I've marked it as Dynamic. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: If the bullet does get instantiated, then method Pistol() gets executed for sure, meaning that the problem must be from your last line of code. Could you please check (via debugging for instance) whether laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() actually manages to return a Rigidbody2D object? It would show as an error in the console if the Rigidbody2D component were null but it wouldn't crash the game so I suppose it could have remained overlooked. Otherwise, if the code truly does return your desired Rigidbody2D, we'll know that the problem lies in "new Vector2(projectileSpeed * direction, 0)"

Comment: I'm kinda new to the whole debugging concept, been watching some tutorials, kinda hard to grasp the concept of it. Do you have any articles/videos for beginners? I will try and see where I can go with this. Will update any issues here. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it truly is an important concept to master. An ugly workaround around debugging is to simply use Debug.Log(); at certain points in your code to check values on-the-fly, thus identifying problems. Could you write Debug.Log(laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()) in your Pistol() method (after the instantiation of the bullet but BEFORE the .addVelocity line) and tell us what it returns in the console when you start the game?

Comment: It says; bullet (Clone) (Unity.Engine.Rigidbody2D). 
Does it mean that I'm missing a prefab or gameObject?

Comment: Nope, it means that the code successfully gets the Rigidbody2D object. Let's try something else then – when the bullet spawns, does it show as static in the editor? And in case it spawns inside a parent, does the parent show as static?

Comment: You mean by the static option in the console. top right? 
The parent object of the bullet, in my case is the player. Both the player and the bullet aren't static. Also I've manually tried setting the value of Projectile speed within the script, still I can't seem to get it working.

I could share my weapon class script here if that would make it any easier.

Comment: Could you then try setting the bullet velocity to a Vector2 with non-zero components, e.g. new Vector2(2.0f, 2.0f)? I do not know if sharing your weapon class would make it easier, but it wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: Adding float values inside the Vector2 as x and y works. The bullet starts flying since I've assigned floats. Except for the direction.

Comment: Then it must be either projectileSpeed or direction that are giving the issue, one of them (or both of them) are 0 when the code gets executed, thus the bullet does not move.

Comment: I tried calling shoot and walk from one class named MovePlayer. It works without any issue. The only issue I get is when I try to separate my fire code block from MovePlayer class to a new class.